Clique Connect: minimum spanning tree (Kruskal vs. Prim)
Problem Statement
You are given a weighted undirected graph G with N vertices, numbered 1 to N. Initially, G has no edges.
You will perform M operations to add edges to G. The i-th operation (1≤i≤M) is as follows:
You are given a subset of vertices Si={Ai,1, Ai,2, ,…,Ai,Ki} consisting of Ki vertices. For every pair u,v such that u,v ∈ Si and u<v, add an edge between vertices u and v with weight Ci.
​
After performing all M operations, determine whether G is connected. If it is, find the total weight of the edges in a minimum spanning tree of G.
Code
from collections import defaultdict


def solution(A):
    class Kruskal:
        def __init__(self, G):
            self.G = G
            self.parent = {}
            self.rank = {}
            self.make_sets()

        def make_sets(self):
            for u, v in self.G:
                if u not in self.parent:
                    self.parent[u] = u
                    self.rank[u] = 0
                if v not in self.parent:
                    self.parent[v] = v
                    self.rank[v] = 0

        def find(self, x):
            if self.parent[x] != x:
                self.parent[x] = self.find(self.parent[x])
            return self.parent[x]

        def union(self, u, v):
            su, sv = self.find(u), self.find(v)
            if su != sv:
                if self.rank[su] > self.rank[sv]:
                    self.parent[sv] = su
                else:
                    self.parent[su] = sv
                    if self.rank[su] == self.rank[sv]:
                        self.rank[sv] += 1

        def _mst(self):
            mst = []
            for edge in self.G.keys():
                u, v = edge
                if self.find(u) != self.find(v):
                    self.union(u, v)
                    mst.append((u, v, self.G[edge]))
            return mst

    N, M = A[0]
    graph = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            k, c = A[i]
        else:
            edges = A[i]
            for ii in range(len(edges)):
                for jj in range(ii + 1, len(edges)):
                    if edges[ii] < edges[jj]:
                        if (edges[jj], edges[ii]) not in graph or (edges[ii], edges[jj]) not in graph:
                            graph[(edges[jj], edges[ii])] = c
                            graph[(edges[ii], edges[jj])] = c
                            continue
                        if (edges[jj], edges[ii]) in graph and graph[(edges[jj], edges[ii])] > c:
                            graph[(edges[jj], edges[ii])] = c
                        if (edges[ii], edges[jj]) in graph and graph[(edges[ii], edges[jj])] > c:
                            graph[(edges[ii], edges[jj])] = c

    kruskal = Kruskal(graph)
    MST = kruskal._mst()
    res = 0
    nodes = set()
    # print(MST)
    for x, y, z in sorted(MST, key=lambda o: o[-1]):
        res += z
        nodes.update({x, y})

    if sorted(nodes) != list(range(1, N + 1)):
        print(-1)
    else:
        print(res)


A = [[10, 5], [6, 158260522], [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10], [10, 877914575], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
     [4, 602436426], [2, 6, 7, 9], [6, 24979445], [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10], [4, 861648772], [2, 4, 8, 9]]

solution(A)




Question
It outputs: 4302960910. The expected output is 1202115217. What did I miss?
Alternative:
from collections import defaultdict
from heapq import heappush, heappop


def solution(A):
    def prim(G):
        vis = set()
        start, dest = next(iter(G))
        vis.add(start)
        Q, mst = [], []
        for (start, nei), w in G.items():
            heappush(Q, (w, start, nei))
        while Q:  # and len(vis) < len(G):
            # print(Q)
            w, src, dest = heappop(Q)
            if dest in vis:
                continue
            vis.add(dest)
            mst.append((src, dest, w))
            for w, nei in G[dest]:
                heappush(Q, (w, dest, nei))
        return mst

    N, M = A[0]
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            k, c = A[i]
        else:
            edges = A[i]
            for ii in range(len(edges)):
                for jj in range(ii + 1, len(edges)):
                    if edges[ii] < edges[jj]:
                        if (edges[jj], edges[ii]) not in graph:
                            graph[(edges[ii], edges[jj])] = c
                            graph[(edges[jj], edges[ii])] = c
                            continue

                        if (edges[jj], edges[ii]) in graph and graph[(edges[jj], edges[ii])] > c:
                            graph[(edges[jj], edges[ii])] = c
                        # if (edges[ii], edges[jj]) in graph and graph[(edges[ii], edges[jj])] > c:
                        #     graph[(edges[ii], edges[jj])] = c

    mst = prim(graph)
    res = 0
    s = set()
    for x, y, w in mst:
        res += w
        s.update({x, y})

    if sorted(s) != list(range(1, N + 1)):
        print(-1)
    else:
        print(res)


A = [[10, 5], [6, 158260522], [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10], [10, 877914575], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
     [4, 602436426], [2, 6, 7, 9], [6, 24979445], [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10], [4, 861648772], [2, 4, 8, 9]]
solution(A)


The alternative algorithm seems to be "partially" working, but I'm still unsure, if it's been implemented correctly?
Pseudocode
algorithm Kruskal(G) is
    F:= ∅
    for each v in G.V do
        MAKE-SET(v)
    for each {u, v} in G.E ordered by weight({u, v}), increasing do
        if FIND-SET(u) ≠ FIND-SET(v) then
            F := F ∪ { {u, v} }
            UNION(FIND-SET(u), FIND-SET(v))
    return F

How to run the code online?

Use my Ideone template.
Change the solution method with your correct solution method.
Submit your code it in this link (A login username and password is required).


Please add pseudocode to your post.

In Kruskal's algorithm, you need to visit the edges in weight-sorted order.  Looks like you are failing to do that, instead sorting the edges after finding the spanning tree for some reason.
Note that the cliques in this question are a trick.  The cost of the MST is unchanged if you just connect the first vertex in each subset to every other one instead of making the whole clique.  That simple optimization makes this an essentially linear time algorithm.
